# Refresh cached image after uploading new image to Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, sdwebimage, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI to retreive images from Firebase storage using the sd_setImage method that accepts a `FIRStorageReference` and `UIImage?` as arguments.

```
myUIImage.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

I have uploaded a new image to Firebase Storage, but it will not be replaced as the documentation states:

> "SDWebImage does very aggressive caching by default. It ignores all
>   kind of caching control header returned by the HTTP server and cache
>   the returned images with no time restriction."

Is there any way to use the `SDWebImageRefreshCached` flag with firebase storage?

> you may use the SDWebImageRefreshCached flag. This will slightly
>   degrade the performance but will respect the HTTP caching control
>   headers:

It seems this would solve my issue and update the image when it has been replaced in Firebase Storage.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question: does the `SDWebImageRefreshCached ` solve the issue or not?

Comment: The methods that accept FIRStorageReference have no arguments for options to allow SDWebImageRefreshCached, it is only available for URL requests. My question was is there a way to utilise SDWebImageRefreshCached with the methods that use FIRStorageReference, or another way to respect the HTTP caching control headers.

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseUI Storage doesn't do anything special with the cache and just treats it as an opaque key-value store, using the storage reference's full path as the key and the image as the value. You can force a re-download by [manually invalidating the cache](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h#L199) or skip the download entirely by [overwriting the cached image](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h#L105).

Comment: Actually I believe this does not really solve the issue as the user does not automatically know when the image was uploaded to properly invalidate the cache. This is the reason why SDWebImage has a flag to respect HTTP cache header as this information is contained there. I second the idea to add another version of sd_setImage to FirebaseStorageUI where you can pass a StorageReference, a placeholder and the option flag for SDWebImage to respect cache header. But this should be requested via an issue for FirebaseStorageUI and not here :)